# Refitting clusters around fixed centroids

Tags: r, classification, cluster-analysis, data-mining

Clustering/classification problem:
Used k-means clustering to generate these clusters and centroids:

This is the dataset with the added cluster attribute from the initial run:

```
  > dput(sampledata)
    structure(list(Player = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
    "D", "E"), class = "factor"), Metric.1 = c(0.3938961, 0.28062338, 
    0.32532626, 0.29239642, 0.25622558), Metric.2 = c(0.00763359, 
    0.01172354, 0.40550867, 0.04026846, 0.05976367), Metric.3 = c(0.50766075, 
    0.20345662, 0.06267444, 0.08661417, 0.17588925), cluster = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Player", "Metric.1", "Metric.2", 
    "Metric.3", "cluster"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

These are the cluster details ran off the 3 metrics:

```
> dput (scluster)
structure(list(cluster = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), centers = structure(c(0.3938961, 
0.276415126666667, 0.32532626, 0.00763359, 0.03725189, 0.40550867, 
0.50766075, 0.155320013333333, 0.06267444), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3"), c("Metric.1", "Metric.2", "Metric.3"))), 
    totss = 0.252759813332907, withinss = c(0, 0.00930902482096013, 
    0), tot.withinss = 0.00930902482096013, betweenss = 0.243450788511947, 
    size = c(1L, 3L, 1L), iter = 1L, ifault = 0L), .Names = c("cluster", 
"centers", "totss", "withinss", "tot.withinss", "betweenss", 
"size", "iter", "ifault"), class = "kmeans")
```

[Data with cluster attribute and centroids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqljU.jpg)

I aim to find a way to fix these centroids after the first cluster run for each cluster, such that these centroids can be used as fixed future references to see how these players move in and out of these clusters to different clusters if their metrics change, thereby tracking their progress or regress.

Specifically, if player A has changes in metrics such that it now resembles cluster 2 rather than 1, based on the Euclidean distance from the respective fixed centroids, I should be able to see player A move to cluster 2. This would mean the data points were refitted around these initially fixed centroids obtained from the first run.

This should help users to know how to approach such a data mining problem. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If you add  to your question using `dput` output from the data-objects you have, there might be a chance that a coding anser would be possible. Without any data, this is too vague and is at serious risk of closure on that basis. (It's already gotten a close vote and so it will now be in the queue where such answers get further reviewed. The way to prevent further close votes is to edit the question body to make it more specific.)

Comment: I've added a dataset which resembles the original along with the output of clusters and centroids. Does this work? I apologize I'm new to stackoverflow but have seen many solutions in the past. Please let me know if this is okay. I appreciate your time in this.

Comment: That would not normally be very helpful to two reasons: 1) people don't really expect to do the data entry when you could have provided it in a text format, and 2) it's probably actually a list object and the structure of the list is what is needed. We only get the structure if you followed my directions to use `dput`.

Comment: @BondedDust  Thanks for patiently responding to me and helping me get through this. Is the post any better now? I am all in for making it as response friendly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
# install a couple of packages needed for the example
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/emclustr")
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/imputation")
library(emclustr)
library(imputation)

# generate some example data -- 30 points in 3 2-dimensional clusters
# clusters are MVN
set.seed(123)
x <- rbind(gen_clust(10, 2, c(-5,5), c(1,1)),
           gen_clust(10, 2, c(0,0), c(1,1)),
           gen_clust(10, 2, c(5,5), c(1,1)))

# get initial centroids
km <- kmeans(x, centers= 3)$centers

# generate a new set of example data, in this case a "subsequent step"
# from your time-series
x2 <- rbind(gen_clust(10, 2, c(-4,-4), c(1,1)),
           gen_clust(10, 2, c(1,1), c(1,1)),
           gen_clust(10, 2, c(4,4), c(1,1)))

# calculate the Euclidean distance of each point to each centroid
# and evaluate nearest distance
d_km <- as.data.frame(cbind(dist_q.matrix(x= rbind(km[1,], x2), ref= 1L, q=2),
              dist_q.matrix(x= rbind(km[2,], x2), ref= 1L, q=2),
              dist_q.matrix(x= rbind(km[3,], x2), ref= 1L, q=2)))
names(d_km) <- c("dist_centroid1", "dist_centroid2", "dist_centroid3")
d_km$clust <- apply(d_km, 1, which.min)

# plot the centroids and the new points "x2" to show the results
plot(km, pch= 11, xlim= c(-6,6), ylim= c(-6,6))
points(x2, col= factor(d_km$clust))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god that's awesome. Thanks Alex. I will look into your detailed solution and get back to you. I greatly appreciate your time and such detailing in this. This is incredible