# k-means cluster analysis in r: setting only one center, leaving the other centers to be computed

Tags: r, center, k-means

I want to cluster datapoints into three groups with k-means. I know the center of one of these three groups, but not of the other two. Therefore, I would like to pre-set the center of the one group and have the algorithm cluster accordingly, keeping that one center fixed. However, I am not sure if and how I can do this with the k-means package in R.

If I do the clustering without pre-setting the center, then the center of the group I know about gets shifted into the direction of the other clusters' centers, which likely leads to false classification.

Thank you for any input.

Juliane

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refitting clusters around fixed centroids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399000/refitting-clusters-around-fixed-centroids)

Comment: Can you add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, we can make our own initialization routine. For example we can modify the Forgy method like this

```
# modified Forgy
set.seed(1)

c1 <- c(7.8, 4.3, 6.8, 2.4)
cn <- rbind(c1, iris[sample(nrow(iris), 2),-5])

kmeans(iris[,-5], cn)$centers
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1     6.684427    2.626896     6.512092  2.09042298
# 2     5.078494    3.646351     1.485264  0.05223007
# 3     6.012102    2.553765     3.869828  1.66717281
```

The first initial centre is fixed, while the rest are selected randomly from the rows in the data set.
Of course this makes the `nstart` argument inapplicable, but we can replicate this functionality easily by repeating the above calculation a bunch of times, and then pick the result with the highest BCSS

```
# modified Forgy with nstart
set.seed(1)
data(iris)
m <- iris[,-5]

# initializing with the actual centroid of the first species
c1 <- colMeans(m[as.integer(iris[,5]) == 1,])
c1
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#        5.006        3.428        1.462        0.246 

kf <- function(x, clust, nc) {
    cn <- rbind(clust, x[sample(nrow(x), nc-1),])
    kmeans(x, cn)
}

l <- replicate(100, kf(m, c1, 3), simplify=FALSE)
bss <- sapply(l, '[[', "betweenss")
table(signif(bss, 4))
# 
# 538.6 602.5 
#    37    63 
kmo <- l[[which.max(bss)]]

kmo$centers
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1     5.006000    3.428000     1.462000    0.246000
# 2     5.901613    2.748387     4.393548    1.433871
# 3     6.850000    3.073684     5.742105    2.071053
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I could apply it to my data, starting with a center of 0/0 for one of the groups.